# Action of Galois group on scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, schemes, galois-extensions

The following exercise is the 2.10 page 97 of Liu's book. Let $k/K$ a finite Galois extension and $X$ a $k-$scheme of finite type over $k$ (i.e. a $k$ algebraic variety).

I have the following questions to solve :

a)Let $L$ an extension of $k$. Show that $G := Gal(k/K)$ acts transitively on $Spec(L \otimes_{k} K)$.

b)Let us suppose $X$ is irreducible. Show that $G$ acts transitively on the
irreducible components of $X_{K}$ . Deduce from this that the irreducible
components of $X_{\bar{k}}$ have the same dimension.

c) Let us suppose $X$ is connected. Show that $G$ acts transitively on the
connected components of $X_{K}$ .

---

Here is what I've done.

a)The action of $G$ on $Spec(L \otimes_{k} K)$ is induced by the $L-$action of $G$ on $L \otimes_{k} K$ (where $\sigma \in G$ act on this space via $Id_{L} \otimes_{k} \sigma$). But we know $Spec(L \otimes_{k} K)$ has at most $dim_{K}(L \otimes_{k} K) = dim_{k}(K) = |G|$ elements (exercice $1.9.$ $(a)$ page $33$; the last equality comming from the fact that $k/K$ is Galois). Writing the class equation, I can't conclude their's only one orbit since they could be smaller than $G$.

b)I suppose the action of $\sigma \in G$ is given by $Id_{X} \otimes_{Spec(k)}  \sigma$? If yes and if we can show the action on the irreducible components  is transitive, then it will be easy to show those irreducible components of $X_{K}$ (but not of $X_{\bar{k}}$ !) are of the same dimension since the $Id_{X} \otimes_{Spec(k)}  \sigma$ are isomorphism.

c)I found this link : [Action of a Galois Group on an Algebraic Variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576635/action-of-a-galois-group-on-an-algebraic-variety) but I don't understand the solution which is exposed.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Have solved 2.3.20? You can use that for part a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Note that $\operatorname{Spec}(L \otimes_k K)$ is a finite discrete topological space. Let $e \in L \otimes_k K$ be a non-invertible idempotent. Then the product $f$ of the $G$-conjugates of $e$ is in $(L \otimes_k K)^G=L$, and is idempotent as well. Since $e$ is not invertible, $f$ cannot be invertible, hence $f=0$.

In particular, suppose that $e$ is chosen equal to $1$ on every connected component but one (let’s call it $C$) where it is zero. For for any connected component $D$ of $X_K$, $f$ vanishes on $D$, so $e$ has a $G$-conjugate vanishing on $D$, so $D$ is in the $G$-orbit of $C$.

c) for affine $X$. The argument above carries over when you replace $L$ by a connected $k$-algebra $A$, and proves that for every closed open subset $C \subset Y:=\operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes_k K)$, the $G$-translates of $C$ cover $Y$.

In particular, let $x \in Y$, then every closed open subspace $C \subset Y$ must contain a point in the $G$-orbit of $x$ (which has cardinality at most $|G|$). It follows that every finite partition of $Y$ into closed open subspaces has cardinality at most $|G|$.

Considering such a partition of maximal cardinality, we find that $T$ is the finite disjoint union of its open connected components. Hence, if $C$ is a connected component of $Y$, then $Y$ is covered by the $G$-translates of $C$, which are also connected components. QED.

c) for general $X$. It’s well-known that the set of connected components (with Galois action) of $X_K$ is the same as that of $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}(X_K)}=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}(X)\otimes_k K)$ (since $K/k$ is flat). But $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}(X)}$ is an affine connected $k$-scheme, so we’re reduced to the case where $X$ is an affine connected $k$-scheme.

b) we can assume $X$ integral. I claim that the irreducible components of $X_K$ are in canonical (in particular, preserving the Galois action) bijection with $\operatorname{Spec}(k(X) \otimes_k K)$.

This can be rephrased as “the generic points of $X_K$ are exactly those in the generic fibre of $X_K \rightarrow X$”.

Now, let $y \in X_K$ be a generic point, lying above $x \in X$. Because $K/k$ is flat, so is $X_K \rightarrow X$, hence $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X_K,y}$ is a flat local morphism. Thus it is faithfully flat, so it induces a surjection of spectra; since $\mathcal{O}_{X_K,y}$ has a single maximal ideal, so does $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, so that $x$ is the generic point of $X$.

Hence the generic fibre of $X_K \rightarrow X$ (a finite morphism) is a *subspace* of $X_K$ stable under generization, containing all the generic points, and is the spectrum of a finite $k(X)$-algebra: it is a finite discrete space! So said generic fibre must be exactly the spectrum of $k(X) \otimes_k K$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hello : for a) : $e$ has a $G$ conjugate vanishing in $D$. Let's calling it $\sigma(e)$ where $\sigma \in G$. How do you conclude $\sigma(c) = D$?

Comment: By construction, $\sigma(e)$ vanishes on exactly one connected component, which should be $\sigma(C)$.

Comment: I get the point my question was stupid. Many thanks for that answer.

Comment: @Analyse300: it wasn’t! You didn’t understand something, which is normal; you realized it and asked about it, which was good! Questions aren’t “stupid” because they have a one-sentence answer.

Comment: Sure. But when someone explains me something I didn't get on my own, I often don't understand. It's a default.